# SimpleMembership - User session logs - login logout history

Tags: c#, simplemembership

Is there a existing feature available in SimpleMembership Asp.net MVC4 to  maintain the user logging history.

**USER  TIME                   ACTIVITY IPADDRESS   DEVICE  BROWSER**

SCOTT   01/02/1311:00:00    LOG IN  10.83.99.10 IPHONE  CHROME…

SCOTT   01/02/1311:30:00    LOG OUT

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't an automagic feature, but you can simply override ValidateUser method of the provider and there save all needed info.

[Here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1869419.aspx/1) you can find some samples

Comment: ok... then how to store log out information if the web application crash or user click close/cross button on browser by mistake?

Comment: This is always impossible to log, by the disconnected nature of web.
You could check at login if the user last session was correctly closed or not (storing last logoff info)